# Extract compressed file - Autohotkey

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey, compression, zip

I have WinRar installed and I would like to know if the program has command line functions to extract the compressed files using a hotkey with autohotkey. I haven't found this, so I've seen other alternatives for this, like:

[https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/23219-extract-from-rar-075-090/](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/23219-extract-from-rar-075-090/%20https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/86876-unrarhk-unrar-your-moviesseries-efortlessly-from-context-menu/%20%20This%20only%20accepts%20.rar%20files:%20viewtopic.php?t=55680%20%20Thank%20you%20in%20advance)
https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/86876-unrarhk-unrar-your-moviesseries-efortlessly-from-context-menu/

This only accepts .rar files:
https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=55680
Thanks in advance

Comment: You misunderstand - the AutoHotKey scripts *call* the WinRar program. Nothing else.

Comment: I understand, but how do I do this?

Comment: The same way that do those scripts you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implementation is used to extract .rar and .zip files and allows you to enter the password if the file contains it:

```
~^q:: ;CTRL + Q = descomprimir

;inicio
7z := "C:\Archivos de programa\7-Zip\7zG.exe"

;guarda una copia del portapapeles
Clipboard_ := ClipboardAll 

;copiar la ruta del archivo comprimido
Send, ^c 
Sleep 100
Send, ^c

;descomprimir
SplitPath, Clipboard, Nombre_Archivo, Directorio,, Nombre_Archivo_NoEXT
RunWait, "%7z%" x "%Clipboard%" -o"%Directorio%\%Nombre_Archivo_NoEXT%",, UseErrorLevel
if (!ErrorLevel) {
    ;FileRecycle, %ClipBoard%
}

;restaura el protapapeles
Clipboard := Clipboard_, Clipboard_ := ""
return
```

Answer (score 1):

What would be the need for that? Most archive tools, such as [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/), can be installed to *automatically* handle all specified file extensions:

- In Windows *Explorer*, select an archive and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or Double-click the file to open the file. In 7-Zip, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>PgDn</kbd> to extract it.
- In Windows *Explorer*, right-click to use context-menu items, such as *Extract archive here*, *Add to archive*, etc.